# Accessing label text via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, radio-button

Is there a way to get the text from a `<label>` element using jquery? Because we're able to get the value from it using `$(this).val();` but are unable to do the same for the label text.

Seems like we should be able to query the `<label>` text using `$(this)` when a radio button is selected since `$(this)` knows its value during that time.

Originally went with case statements and manually filling in some text but if we're able to just insert the label text instead then that would negate the need for all the case statements being used.

thoughts/suggestions?

**html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordion-second">What You Are Interested In Learning About</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordion-second" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="2a">the Automotive Industry</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="2b">the sports industry</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="2c">the music industry</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
    $('[name="optradio2"]').on('change', function () {
        $('#accordion-third').slideToggle();
        $('#accordion-second').slideToggle();

        //how do you get the label text 
        var labelText = $("label", this).text();

        //current method but would prefer to just insert the label text
        /*var value = $(this).val();
        switch (value) {
            case "2a":
                $('#blank2', $('#myModal')).text('the automotive industry');
                break;
            case "2b":
                $('#blank2', $('#myModal')).text('the sports industry');
                break;
            case "2c":
                $('#blank2', $('#myModal')).text('the music industry');
                break;
            default:
                alert("oops! something went wrong");
        }*/
})
</script>
```

Comment: `$('input:radio[name=optradio2]:checked').closest('label').text();`

Comment: This solution worked as well. Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context selector uses `find` and searches for descendants.

The label is not a child of the input, it's the other way around, so you have to look for parents, and `closest` seems to fit

```
var labelText = $(this).closest("label").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the relevant `<label>`, using the `HTMLInputElement.labels` Property, which returns a NodeList of `<label>` elements associated with that specific `<input>`, using array-index notation to get (usually) the first:

```
this.labels[0].textContent;
```

References:

- [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: I keep getting an error `Unable to get property of '0' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Your browser may not implement that property, perhaps. Although I'd double-check that your `this` is, in fact, the `<input>`.

Comment: I'm using IE so it could be the browser. During debugging it does show that `this` is `[object HTMLInputElement]`; also can see that `childNodes` = `[object NodesList]` -- however the length is `0`